# I want to return the same item twice in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

A very simple question. Couldn't find something similar here (maybe I didn't use the right wording. Sorry in advance).

I have a table:

```
| ID | FullName   |
-------------------
| 1  | Frank Owa  |
| 2  | Gail Sorbe |
```

I wish the query to display all the users that contains the string either 'ran' or 'wa'.

And that includes duplicates.

So, what I expect to get is:

```
|ID | FullName  |
-----------------
|1  | Frank Owa |
|1  | Frank Owa |
```

Because Frank Owa has either 'ran' or 'wa'. And I wish to display it twice as a result.

But the query will display the result only once.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE FullName LIKE '%ran%' OR FullName LIKE '%wa%'
```

What did I do wrong?...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query checks on an either-or basis - if a row meets any of the 2 conditions, it is included once and then the next row is checked. If you want it to appear twice on account of meeting 2 different conditions, you could use UNION ALL, like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE FullName LIKE '%ran%'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE FullName LIKE '%wa%'
```

Comment: Nope. Like I said, as long as one of the conditions is met, the record will be included in the result and the query will move on to the next.

Comment: Roger. i'll do that. Thanx!

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to mark an answer that was helpful as accepted. This serves to indicate that the question has an accepted solution which can be used for similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FullName LIKE '%ran%'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FullName LIKE '%wa%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a Union All between queries that fetch names containing 'ran' and and query that fetches 'wa'.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE FullName LIKE '%ran%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE FullName LIKE'%wa%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the condition is dynamic and you cannot write `UNION ALL` every time you have to do it dynamically.

You sample table

```
SELECT * INTO #TABLE
FROM
(
   SELECT 1 Id, 'Frank Owa' FullName
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2,'Gail Sorbe'
)TAB
```

Now you need to split the values and insert into a temparery table.

```
DECLARE @Split VARCHAR(1000);
SET @Split = 'ran,wa';

DECLARE @x XML;
SET @x = '<r>' + REPLACE((SELECT @Split FOR XML PATH('')), ',', '</r><r>') + '</r>';
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY y.XmlCol.value('(text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(1000)'))RNO,
 y.XmlCol.value('(text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS Value
INTO #TEMP
FROM    @x.nodes('/r') y(XmlCol);
```

Now, the following code will write `UNION ALL` dynamically for you

```
DECLARE @I INT=1
DECLARE @COUNT INT    
DECLARE @QRY NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @CONDITION NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @NAME NVARCHAR(MAX)    

SELECT @COUNT=COUNT(*) FROM #TEMP       

-- Loop will be executed for the number of parameters, ie, for your above example,
-- @COUNT will be 2. 
WHILE(@I <= @COUNT)
BEGIN

 -- Select ran on first loop wa on second loop etc
 SELECT @NAME = Value FROM #TEMP WHERE RNO= @I

 SET @CONDITION = 'SELECT * FROM #TABLE WHERE FullName LIKE ''%' + @NAME +  '%'' UNION ALL '
 SELECT @QRY = COALESCE(@QRY,'') + @CONDITION 
 SET @I=@I+1;

END
```

Now you need to remove last `UNION ALL` and execute the query dynamically

```
SELECT @QRY = LEFT(@QRY, LEN(@QRY)-9)
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @QRY
```

Here is the result

[image]

Comment: Hi Yael. Is this the result was you were expecting? @Yael