# SUM query's result which contain UNION ALL and CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Even though I found something similar to what I was needed, I wasn't able to work it out.

So, I'll ask using my example.

(It is in continuation to my prev question: [select if there are more than n results but with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27518482/select-if-there-are-more-than-n-results-but-with-conditions))

My Table:

```
| TimeId | Work_Role | User_Name |
----------------------------------
|    1   | users     | Oran      | 
|    2   | admin     | Ray       |
|    3   | users     | Oran      | 
|    4   | servs     | Amit      |
|    5   | admin     | Oran      |
|    6   | users     | Ray       |
|    7   | users     | Oran      | 
|    8   | servs     | Amit      |
|    9   | admin     | Oran      |
|   10   | users     | Oran      |
```

I've used CTE to display a list for user_name = "Oran" and Work_Role = "users" ONLY if there are more than 2 in the table.

In addition, I used Union all to gather another part  that it's condition is: user_name = "Oran" and Work_Role = "admin".

The result is:

```
| TimeId | Work_Role | User_Name |
----------------------------------
|    1   | users     | Oran      | 
|    3   | users     | Oran      | 
|    7   | users     | Oran      | 
|   10   | users     | Oran      |
|    5   | admin     | Oran      | 
|    9   | admin     | Oran      |
```

My second part (which there I have the problem) is to count how many lines the result above has.

**In this case I expect: 6**

My code for the first result (which is working fine):

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *, cc = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY User_Name) FROM Table
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE
    Work_Role = 'users' 
    AND User_Name = 'Oran'
    AND cc > 2
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE
   Work_Role = 'admin' 
   AND User_Name = 'Oran'
```

How can I **summarize** the lines' number of the final result?

Can it even be done while using CTE?

**NOTE:**
This is just an example. In my real code I must use the "UNION ALL" :-(

10X!

Answer (score 0):

First, you can simplify the query to:

```
WITH CTE AS (
      SELECT t.*, cc = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY User_Name) FROM Table t
     )
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE (Work_Role = 'users' AND User_Name = 'Oran' AND cc > 2) OR
      (Work_Role = 'admin' AND User_Name = 'Oran');
```

The nice thing is that this will also work, because the two subqueries have the same columns.

If you want to count the number of rows, just use `select count(*)`:

```
WITH CTE AS (
      SELECT t.*, cc = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY User_Name) FROM Table t
     )
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM CTE
WHERE (Work_Role = 'users' AND User_Name = 'Oran' AND cc > 2) OR
      (Work_Role = 'admin' AND User_Name = 'Oran');
```

Comment: Thanx, but the example I gave is not the real code. Unfortunatly, the real code force me to use "UNION ALL" and not "OR" :-(

Comment: That was my question that forced me to use "UNION ALL":
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498044/i-want-to-return-the-same-item-twice-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Ok, eventually I've found an answer, lol

It is based on the first answer of this question: [Sum a union query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613728/sum-a-union-query)

1. I had to alias my derived table.
2. Set the additional select (with the SUM) between the "THIS" and it's "SELECT".
3. Change to COUNT for each query and alias it.

Like so:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *, cc = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY User_Name) FROM Table
)
SELECT SUM(my_dervied_table.total_lines) FROM (
SELECT COUNT(*) as 'total_lines'
FROM CTE
WHERE
    Work_Role = 'users' 
    AND User_Name = 'Oran'
    AND cc > 2
UNION ALL
SELECT  COUNT(*) as 'total_lines' 
FROM TABLE
WHERE
   Work_Role = 'admin' 
   AND User_Name = 'Oran'
) my_dervied_table
```

So instead of counting the lines in this output:

```
| TimeId | Work_Role | User_Name |
----------------------------------
|    1   | users     | Oran      | 
|    3   | users     | Oran      | 
|    7   | users     | Oran      | 
|   10   | users     | Oran      |
|    5   | admin     | Oran      | 
|    9   | admin     | Oran      |
```

I'm actually summing the 'total_lines' column's content of the "my_derived_table": 4+2 = 6

```
    | total_lines |
    ---------------
 1) |      4      |
 2) |      2      |
```

Answer (score 0):

shalom yael-try this code-

```
   WITH CTE AS 

(
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE
    Work_Role = 'users' 
    AND User_Name = 'Oran'
    AND ( select COUNT(user_name)  
          FROM tbl
          WHERE user_name='oran') > 2
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM tbl
WHERE
   Work_Role = 'admin' 
   AND User_Name = 'Oran')
   SELECT count([User_Name]) total_lines  
   from cte
   GROUP BY [Work_Role],[User_Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this,

```
Declare @t table(TimeId int,Work_Role varchar(50),User_Names varchar(50))
insert into @t values
 (1  , 'users','Oran'      ), 
(   2 ,'admin', 'Ray'),
(   3 ,'users', 'Oran'),
(    4,'servs', 'Amit'),
(    5,'admin', 'Oran'),
(    6,'users', 'Ray'),
(    7,'users', 'Oran'),
(    8,'servs', 'Amit'),
(    9,'admin', 'Oran'),
(   10,'users', 'Oran')
;With CTE as
(
   select *,
   ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by User_Names,Work_Role order by timeid)rn 
   from @t
)
   select * from CTE where Work_Role = 'users' 
    AND User_Names = 'Oran'
    AND exists
    (
    select User_Names from CTE where rn>2 
    and Work_Role = 'users' AND User_Names = 'Oran'
    )

 UNION ALL
  select * from CTE where Work_Role = 'admin' 
  AND User_Names = 'Oran'
```